# Where I can find my server.js file in my react application?

Tags: reactjs

[image]

Where I can find server.js or index.js in my node server for react. I need to change the configuration for the cors problem

Edit: I am using IntelliJ

Comment: are you using CreactReactApp boilerplate?

Answer (score 0):

If your using vscode, you can use the search function that searches threw all files, its the eyeglass icon